# How to configure my xbee s2c modules for communicating with arduinos + sensors?

Tags: arduino, communication, xbee, zigbee

I have two xbee module (fixed on a development board), these boards does not have a individual access pins to access xbee pins (photo included), but rather a RS232 port.

As for what I have searched, there are two ways to configure your xbee for communication. One is to use software *Coolterm* [from here.](https://download.cnet.com/CoolTerm/3000-2094_4-10915882.html) Second way is two use XCTU software [from here.](https://www.digi.com/products/xbee-rf-solutions/xctu-software/xctu)

**Using Coolterm**
This requires arduino to configure it. [This is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0WTsiocpIs&t=535s). 
Circuit : 
[image: TX is connected to DB9 port (TX), RX of arduino is connected to DB9 port (RX)]
[image]

Problem: I am not able to get any reply from xbee, as when i type "+++", result should be "+++OK". But nothing is coming.

Question: Is this the right way to connect arduino and the xbee? I am using single stranded wires, and inserting them directly.

**Using XCTU**
I do not know if it requires arduino or no. [Video I referred](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBkQUph9EKM&t=390s)
Here I used a RS232 to USB adapter and connected it to the laptop. 
[image]
My device manager is showing that the COM5 is connected, but in XCTU, it is not able to search my xbee. I tried my both xbees.

Problem: My XCTU is not detecting the xbee connected to the USB port via an adapter which is directly connected to xbee. Arduino is there to provide power only, no other connections are there.

Question: Is this the right way to do it? What do i have to do so that it will be detected. 
This RS232 port is creating problems?

Answer (score 1):

**X-CTU**

I recommend X-CTU as it is the official Digi programming software, allows Over-the-Air programming, console access, and more. **X-CTU has nothing to do with Arduino**. Here is the USB adapter board I use [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00UBFM03Y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UBFM03Y)

Make sure if using it on linux, you add yourself to the dialout group. Example: `sudo usermod -a -G dialout chris`

Make sure Arduino IDE or other programs which use COM ports are closed when working with XCTU. Radio discovery can be finnicky, but it works when it works.

XCTU's download links on Digi's website are sometimes broken. Find the filename from the download page, then manually browse their ftp server for the correct version of XCTU.

If you can't get XCTU to communicate with your XBee, the rule of thumb is keep trying. It doesn't always work the first or second time. Try the different connection methods as well, from discovery to manually entering XBee serial/USB configuration. Double check the wiring as documented by your dev board.

X-CTU will only find your XBee when you have the correct baud rate entered. Your X-Bee may be in a different baud rate than you expect. When making a connection to your XBee, Use XCTU to automatically scan through all the different baud rates.

You may need to power cycle your XBee right before connecting to it, either by shorting two pins or pressing a reset button. To determine if this is necessary, check the documentation of your XBee development board.

**Power**

The XBee is very sensitive when it comes to power. It needs as close to 3.3V as possible. If you are attempting to remotely program the XBee using X-CTU, and the read process seems slow, it may be that the XBee is crashing when it tries to pull power. Check voltages and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah I have made sure that 3.3v is going into the xbee, and I checked every baud rate box to search for the xbee but the xbee still was not found. Is there anything i have to configure before trying this? [I used this link to download XCTU](https://www.digi.com/products/xbee-rf-solutions/xctu-software/xctu#productsupport-utilities)